# xfsettingsd Unhappy with Monitor Resolution and Bombing Out

Tags: linux, xfce

If I boot my laptop with a HDMI monitor plugged in XFCE will recognise the monitor and display the UI. However, it will reset at least my theme and keyboard settiings with what looks like the xfce defaults.
If I boot without plugging in the monitor, and then plug in the monitor once my user session has started, I can use ArandR to send output to the HDMI monitor and all my settings remain in-tact whilst the screen works perfectly

I see the following in my logs when the error occurs (booting with hdmi monitor plugged in):

```
Nov 04 17:34:26 nickT_Arch systemd[1]: Started Authorization Manager.
Nov 04 17:34:26 nickT_Arch slim[265]: (xfsettingsd:834): xfsettingsd-WARNING **: Unknown mode '1920x1080 @ 30.0' for output HDMI1.
Nov 04 17:34:26 nickT_Arch slim[265]: The program 'xfsettingsd' received an X Window System error.
Nov 04 17:34:26 nickT_Arch slim[265]: This probably reflects a bug in the program.
Nov 04 17:34:26 nickT_Arch slim[265]: The error was 'BadMatch (invalid parameter attributes)'.
Nov 04 17:34:26 nickT_Arch slim[265]: (Details: serial 143 error_code 8 request_code 140 minor_code 7)
Nov 04 17:34:26 nickT_Arch slim[265]: (Note to programmers: normally, X errors are reported asynchronously;
Nov 04 17:34:26 nickT_Arch slim[265]: that is, you will receive the error a while after causing it.
Nov 04 17:34:26 nickT_Arch slim[265]: To debug your program, run it with the --sync command line
Nov 04 17:34:26 nickT_Arch slim[265]: option to change this behavior. You can then get a meaningful
Nov 04 17:34:26 nickT_Arch slim[265]: backtrace from your debugger if you break on the gdk_x_error() function.)
```

Once that has happened it looks like xfsettingsd just stops working. When I run xfsettingsd from the command line I get the following error:

```
(xfsettingsd:1508): xfsettingsd-WARNING **: Unknown mode '1920x1080 @ 30.0' for output HDMI1.

The program 'xfsettingsd' received an X Window System error.
This probably reflects a bug in the program.
The error was 'BadMatch (invalid parameter attributes)'.
  (Details: serial 144 error_code 8 request_code 140 minor_code 7)
  (Note to programmers: normally, X errors are reported asynchronously;
   that is, you will receive the error a while after causing it.
   To debug your program, run it with the --sync command line
   option to change this behavior. You can then get a meaningful
   backtrace from your debugger if you break on the gdk_x_error() function.)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is reported upstream https://bugzilla.xfce.org/show_bug.cgi?id=9680

Still, there's probably just the --sync workaround, nothing better.